# downloading image file using ftp in c#, image file size bounded by fixed size array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, image, ftp

i am trying to download a image file using ftp, on every code i have looked up a `fixed sized array` is being used (as `bufferSize` is being used in below code), how can i efficiently work around this and resize the buffer at run time as i am dealing with images of significant size.

```
 string[] ftpInfo = (string[])e.Argument;

            string uri = String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}/images/{2}", ftpInfo[1], ftpInfo[2], ftpInfo[5]);

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpInfo[3], ftpInfo[4]);

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            long cl = response.ContentLength;
            int bufferSize = 4096;  //Image file cannot be greater than 40 Kb
            int readCount = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            response.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to work around? The fixed size array is the buffer. You read the stream in chunks into the buffer.

Comment: yes fixed sized array is the buffer & i am reading stream in  chunks

Comment: so what's the problem? What are you trying to work around?

Comment: if array size is fixed i could have overflow issues so i wanted to do resize the array at run time

Comment: +1 Maxim. What is the problem? Does the file not get downloaded? After the while loop, the entire file is in memory, courtesy of the MemoryStream. If you need to save the file to disk, skip the MemoryStream and create a FileStream instead through System.IO.File.Create

Comment: No, there will be no overflow issues with the buffer, but there might by Out of Memory issues with the MemoryStream.

Comment: @atornblad i dont want the file to be saved on disc, i am only downloading the file to be uploaded somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have any overflow issues.

```
ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

ensures that you won't read more than 'bufferSize'.

So you read a chunk of size up to bufferSize, write it to the `MemoryStream` and continue reading the next chunk.

If you're concerned about the size of data you write to the `MemoryStream` you can use another `Stream`, for example `FileStream`.

Comment: but the image will not downloaded completely as buffer will be trucated once the full capacity has been reached.

Comment: The while loop ensures that the file is completely downloaded, 4096 bytes at a time. Maxim has the correct answer for you.

Comment: @jaminator - are you sure that it doesn't work well?
Try to save it to a file and open the image.